# Run the project this error keeps popping up

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I run or rebuild the project this error keeps popping up.

[image]

I tried to clean the project then rebuilding it.
I am using the latest version of visual studio.

I was trying to run the app but these errors keep popping up.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the uses of that drawable file like how and where are you using this drawable file?

Comment: These drawables doesn't even exist.
I don't know why this error suddenly appears.

Comment: If you create a new MAUI project with default template, does this even happen?

Comment: I managed to fix it when i have updated the nuget everything works fine.